# Pre-L application changes to work on L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a perfectly working application on Android 4.4.4 Kitkat and below. When i run this application on a device with L-Preview, it crashes, giving me NullPointerException. So, inorder to test the application, i want to change the application's minSdkVersion to L, and run it on an emulator.

Important Note: There are no controls in the application that are specific to L-Preview. I am using Eclipse.

Here is what i have done till now...

1. Updated SDK and Support libraries to the latest versions.
2. Created an Emulator with Target as Android L.
3. Changed the Java Compiler settings for application to 1.7
4. In the application:

   (i) In AndroidManifest.xml, changed minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to L.
           android:minSdkVersion="L"
           android:targetSdkVersion="L"

   (ii) In Project Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target, checked Android L(Preview).

As soon as i make these changes, and building the application, there are erros in the application and gen folder becomes empty (Is there some issue with Layouts or Styles? Shoudl i be creating a values-v21 folder in layout and use a different theme? Material Theme? and also a drawable-v21?). When i change back the settings to Pre-L settings that are originally there in the application, everything gets back to normal.

What other changes should i be doing for this to work on a device with L. or Atleast get rid of errors and make this application start on the device with L? Most of the errors are because of R.java that goes missing from gen as soon as i make changes.

Comment: can you show a stack trace of the null pointer exception?

Comment: I think this is not a bug with the code. The NPE was near a line that is setting webViewClient to a webview. But, since this works perfectly well in all pre-L devices, i am guessing this is not the line I should be looking at.

Comment: I know, but it would give a bit of a start-out to where the Android code crashes. It helped when the `setText()` function on a TextView crashed because it had no LayoutParams, and that wasn't an obvious coding error either (because it also just threw an NPE).

Comment: I don't have the logcat trace now with me. It was tested on someother's device. Will update the question once i get the trace again. If you can suggest any other changes in the meantime, let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Not much we can specifically help with without a stack trace... but a recommendation would be to run the CheckJNI tool as Android L tightened up JNI compliance. It might or might not help you towards solving your problem but it could shed some light.

Here is info about how to run the tool: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#extended_checking